# Reading float numbers from a .txt to a float matrix using scanner

Tags: java, file, matrix

I'm stucked on a very simple exercise and I can't find the mistake in my code.

I have a text file that looks like this:

> 3
>
> 230.24415 134.34523 166.47234
>
> 192.02849 138.28403 294.12875
>
> 198.97356 256.49284 140.41526

The first (the integer) number indicates the matrix dimension, in this case is 3x3, and the following values are float numbers of 5 decimal places, separated by space and new lines, that have to be setted in a matrix in order to operate with them. That's the main issue of this exercise.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fileToMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        File f = new File("./src/floatMat.txt");
        Scanner s = null;
    
        int m=-1;
        float value = -0.1f;

        try {

            s = new Scanner(f);
        
            if(s.hasNextLine()) {    // Firstly, read the dimension number
                m = s.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Dimension of the matrix = " + m + "x" + m);
            
            }
        
            float [][] mat = new float[m][m];    //creates a matrix of dimension m
            for(int i=0; i< m; i++){    //and initializes to 0
                for(int j=0; j< m; j++){
                    mat[i][j] = 0.0f;
                }            
            }
        
            if(s.hasNextLine()) {
                for(int r=0; r< m; r++){
                    for(int c=0; c< m; c++){
                        value = s.nextFloat(); //PROBABLY HERE'S THE MISTAKE!!!!!
                        mat[r][c] = value;  //set value on the current cell of the array
                    }            
                }
            }
        
            for(int i=0; i< m; i++){ //print the matrix
                for(int j=0; j< m; j++){
                   System.out.print(mat[i][j]+ " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        
        
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Message catch: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (s != null)
                    s.close();
        }
     }
    }
```

I'm sure that the mistake is around my comment notifying the mistake, because it seems that it doesn't recognize the float numbers of my .txt. In fact, if I put integer numbers on my .txt file it almost works!!

It only prints "Dimension of the matrix = 3x3", but then prints "Message catch: null", it doesn't even prints the filled matrix.

Thank you all, I appreciate your help!

Comment: replace `System.out.println("Message catch: " + ex.getMessage());` with `ex.printStackTrace();` check what the exception is and what line throws it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(s.hasNextLine()) {
    for(int r=0; r< m; r++){
        for(int c=0; c< m; c++){
            value = s.nextFloat(); //PROBABLY HERE'S THE MISTAKE!!!!!
            mat[r][c] = value;  //set value on the current cell of the array
        }
```

At this point you've read all three (*N*) floats on the line, so you need `s.nextLine()` here to advance to the next line.

```
    }
}
```

Comment: It's true that I need to avance to the next line. Also before `if(s.hasNextLine())` it's needed to put `s.nextLine()`. But It still doesn't working, the main issue is that the program ins't reading any float numbers... Thank you anyway, @EJP